# Three programs are saying VT-x isnt enabled, even though my BIOS says VT-x is enabled

Tags: windows-10, virtualization

- Windows 10
- Intel i7 5820k
- MSI x99a sli plus mobo

When I go to the BIOS, it says Intel VT-x  is enabled.

When I go on Windows 10, I run a program called leomoon cpu-v. It tells me VT-x isn't enabled. I have an Android emulator called nox. Nox says VT-x isn't enabled.

I tried to make a Windows server virtual machine with Oracle VMWare but when I tried to enable hyper-v on the VM, it said I couldn't because VT-x wasn't enabled, even though on the VM settings it showed VT-x  was enabled.

*Leomoon is also saying my CPU isnt VT-x capable, even though according to [cnet](https://www.cnet.com/products/intel-core-i7-5820k-3-3-ghz-processor/specs/), it is.

Comment: Sounds like you have security software that's using the extension and not allowing your other software to use it

Comment: Just avira. I did a clean install of windows 10, but before I did the clean install I had avira and it never caused any issue

Comment: So before you had that clean install you had VT-x enabled with Avira installed in any of those programs?

Comment: @Avira is know to be a program with security features that use this extension so disable that security feature

Answer (score 0):

There are several programs that loosely speaking capture the vtx extension. Intel HAXM is one.  I think Android studio may do some funny things here too. You can check the virtualbox vbox log to see what it thinks as it can be very informative. Vbox bug report 10649 has extra guidance as does Intels HAXM page.